# Parallax and Fade In ViewPager animations

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'd like to reproduce the same animation in link below, is it a parallax and fade In animations ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni0he.jpg

How could I get the same result using `ViewPager.PageTransformer`

Thank you

Comment: posted an answer.. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For parallax and scrolling use this code below

```
public class Transformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        if (position <= -1 || position >= 1) {
            page.setAlpha(0.0F);
        } else if( position == 0.0f) {
            //page.setAlpha(1);
        } else {
            page.findViewById(R.id.background)
                    .setTranslationX(-position * page.getWidth() / 2);
            //page.setAlpha(1.0f - Math.abs(position));
        }
    }
}
```

where id `background` is the image id you are placing.
And assign it to viewpager by

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new Transformer());
```

Comment: just tested the code, the animation isn't the same + I think `page.setAlpha(1);` is missing on the else statement